# My Ubuntu System lags a lot when connected to internet

Tags: networking, 21.10

I am using Ubuntu 21.10 and my whole system lags too much while connected to the Internet. The keyboard is slow, animations are slow, and cursor is laging a lot. My CPU usage is also much higher:

[image: when connected to internet]

This problem automatically fixes itself when I turn on airplane mode, though:

[image: when not connected to internet][no application is running then also it's using so much of cpu and received 8.2MiB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUywO.jpg)

How to fix this problem? Is this because of virus or something?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include two screenshots of `top`, sorted by CPU usage? One should be taken when the computer is *not* connected to the Internet. The other should be taken when the computer *is* connected and running slowly. With this, it will be possible to identify if there is a specific process that is consuming too many resources (such as a backup or file sync service) 

Comment: Done sorry it took time because my computer is hanging too much

Comment: The screenshots certainly prove the point, however, it would be more helpful to see the “Processes” tab, as that will show which applications/services are causing the problem 

Comment: the memory load of your system is way to high,at idle it should be in the range  of 1,5-2gig please post the first few lines when you type top in the terminal.

Comment: When my wifi is on the gnome-shell uses up to 30% of cpu but when internet is off it only uses 3%

Comment: @trondhansen hey i added top